# How can I disable KDE Alt-` behaviour

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

After upgrading my Linux Slackware, KDE started to respond to a new key shortcut, which did not happen before.

When I click Alt-`, I see the icon of the current window with it's title in the center of the screen.

The problem is, I have this shortcut bound to my Emacs bookmarks list and I can't use it anymore.

How can I disable KDE reaction for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to  Settings -> Window Behavior -> Task Switcher and change the shortcut for current application.